# PowerBI service deployment pipelines and sources

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have 3 workspaces for datasets dev-test-prod and 3 for reports dev-test-prod in Power BI Service.

I'm using deployment pipelines to move datasets and reports between environments; how to ensure that the report deployed from dev to test will point to the dataset from test, not dev? Is this possible in Power BI Service, or requires a complicated configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case:

> Deployment pipelines automatically connects (autobind) the deployed
> item to the item it depends on in the deployed stage. For example, if
> you deploy a paginated report from development to test, and it's
> connected to a Power BI dataset that was previously deployed to the
> test stage, it automatically connects to that dataset.

And you can read about the additional senarios there too: [The deployment pipelines process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-process#auto-binding)